# Handling actionbar items from asynctask inside a fragment of ViewPager and Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-orientation

**Scenario:**
I have a `MainActivity` hosting a `ViewPager` and `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which holds 2 fragments. Both fragment uses same class to extend `Fragment`.

Each fragment has a `ListView` and `AsyncTask`. Data is getting downloaded by `AsyncTask` and in `onPostExecute` I'm re-initiating `ListViewAdapter` and setting a data to `ListView`.

In `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` I want to manipulate some actionbar items including setting `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)`. Biggest problem is `OrientationChange`. If the orientation is changed it does not keep up with my asyncTask and also does not keep up with current actionbar status.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) and made changes to my fragment. Still no use. I'm not able to keep up with visibility of some views and some actionbar menu items.

Is there any way to save the status of actionbar and asyncTask and reload it once the configuration change is completed?

**Shall I create my actionbar menu item in hosting activity? Or in Fragment?**
ActionBarMenu Items are same for both Fragments